# AspNetCore.Identity UserManager in Repository Pattern

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, repository-pattern

I want to use Repository with AspNetCore.Identity UserManager. But I am getting error when defined in Controller.

**Repository**

```
public class TestRepository
{
    private readonly UserManager<tblApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public TestRepository(UserManager<tblApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        this._userManager = userManager;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    private TestRepository _testRepository;

    public TestController()
    {
        this._testRepository = new TestRepository(new UserManager<tblApplicationUser>);
    }
```

I am getting error in controller at *new UserManager*

Comment: include usermanager namespace in controller

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity namespace is already added.

Comment: You mean a compile error? Please add the error to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing braces (for UserManager constructor) before the last brace?

```
this._testRepository = new TestRepository(new UserManager<tblApplicationUser>());
```

You should let the DI handle instantiation of UserManager and Repository. You can check out [this article on official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api#add-a-repository-class) for ASP.NET Core.